# How to connect to Google Analytics in a Meteor app (for receiving data)?

Tags: meteor, google-analytics-api

I am trying to hook up Google Analytics API to a meteor app using this package: 
https://github.com/andruschka/meteor-ga-fetcher

It's a fairly straightforward package, basically a wrapper for some Analytics api library.

I am stuck where it asks to add a key.pem file to the Meteor app and link to it.  How do you include a filepath to a file in Meteor?

I have tried putting key.pem in /private, /server, etc. and giving a path to it (private/key.pem) with no luck. I can't find any resources on how Meteor handles file paths like this.

Or is there a better method for connecting to Analytics with Meteor?

Comment: Instead of having it referenced as a file, could you instead just use a string in your source code?  This assumes the "source" of Meteor is not visible.